# EndIcon is default displayed when set text in TextInputLayout

Tags: kotlin, textinputlayout

I want to know how to hide by default

When the screen is rotated or setText () is displayed in the same way

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/addressTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label2">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:hint=""
        android:text="test"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension function of TextInputEditText to set the text and disable the endIcon for the parent layout.

```
fun TextInputEditText.setTextWithoutEndIcon(content: String, parentLayout: TextInputLayout){
this.setText(content)
parentLayout.isEndIconVisible = false
}
```

So just pass the textInputLayout of that edittext and it will disable the endIcon. Be careful to not pass other edittext's textInputLayout.

Also, I would suggest to make a customTextInputEditText and put this function in there which would give you better flexibility and you would be able to define your purposes in a better way. This way, you can have the material TextInputEditText with it's default properties (unmodified) and your own textinputEditText (modified).

Cheers!